# Индексация страниц привязанных через шаблон через include

Tags: php, seo

У меня сайт устроен следующим образом. 
Есть шаблон внешнего вида сайта, а контент находится в отдельных файлах, в контенте есть только html разметка, ну и естественно все теги мета и title находятся в файлах контента.
А привязаны файлы к шаблону посредствам функции if и команды include.

Так у меня вопрос. Индексируется ли поисковыми системами мой контент? Судя по данным webmaster.yandex.ru у меня индексируется только главная страница, а остальных он не видит.

Почему не видит и как сделать чтобы индексировал и все остальные страницы? 
Ссылка на внутренние страницы выглядит следующим образом: `index.php?page=name`
Код которым добавляется ссылка внутрь шаблона такой:

```
<?php   
if ($_GET['page'] && file_exists("content/".$_GET['page'].".html"))  
{require("content/".$_GET['page'].".html");}  
else require("content/start.html");  
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

если нету, то добавте карту сайта xml на сайт.
и можно ли переходить на страницы типа "**index.php?page=name**" через какое либо меню,
в файле [robots.txt](http://robots.txt) должны стоять нужные разрешения для поисковых машин